# How can I collapse a nested list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a nested list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>stuff2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>stuff3</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href='#'>stuff4</a></li>
</ul>
```

...and want to collapse the nested ul when the li is clicked.  Before I was using

```
$('UL LI').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

...but this obviously causes a problem when a li doesn't have a ul nested after it.  Is there a better way to do this, or is there a way for me to determine if the object returned by $(this).next() is a UL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if($(this).next().is("ul")) {

}
```

Should do the trick. See: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks... I knew it was something simple, but apparently the quick ref guide I'm using doesn't have the .is() method listed.

Comment: This is a sibling check. If the UL is a child or parent of the LI, it will not see it. In the case that you posted, the UL has no LI brethren.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('LI').toggle(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
},
function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
});
```

This is assuming that you mean the UL listed under the LI that is clicked. If you want a particular UL to collapse whenever *any* LI is clicked, you might have to write something with a few more checks.

Comment: This just sets my whole list to hidden and I can't see the top level <li>s anymore.

Answer (score 1):

can it be just $(this).next("ul").slideUp()

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but...

```
$('UL LI').click(function() {
  $('> ul', this).toggle();
});
```